# Are there any drawbacks of using left join of smaller table with larger table vs inner join of two tables and right joining smaller table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Consider I have 2 tables,

- A (1000 rows)
- B (1B rows)

Left table: A
Right table: B

I need to left join A with B, as  I want all rows of A to remain in the output.

As expected, we can't broadcast A (to speed up) if I am doing a left join.

```
D = A.join(B,'key','left)
```

So, I have been doing an inner join of A & B, which allows broadcast. The intermediate output, say C, is much smaller table. I then left join A with C.
In my experience, this is much much faster, and uses lesser resources as well.

```
C = B.join(F.broadcast(A),'key','inner')
D = C.join(A, 'key','right')
```

Is there any drawback to this approach? Missing out on edge cases?

Answer (score 2):

If the `key` is unique in `A`, then this should work.

However, if the key is duplicated, you could increase the number of rows.

This is probably way this optimization is not built into the compiler for `left join`.  Even if the keys are duplicated you could -- with a bit more effort -- get your approach to work.